# Dockerfile, mount host windows folder over server

Tags: linux, windows, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to mount a folder of the host machine to `docker container` but without success. I have the following setup:

1. `Windows` machine
2. From 1 I access `linux` server
3. On 2 I create a `docker` container that should be able to access files on 1

In the `dockerfile` I do the following:

```
ADD //G/foo/boo /my_project/boo
```

This throws an error that the *folder cannot be found*, since the container tries to access the folder on `linux`. However, I do want the container to access the windows machine.

Ideally without copying the files from the source to target folder. I am not sure if `ADD` copies the files or just gives an opportunity to access files.

Comment: Hi abe, Ask on SuperUser.

Comment: @Peter, thanks, here is the link - https://superuser.com/questions/1585935/dockerfile-mount-host-windows-folder-over-server

Comment: Docker doesn't have any special support for accessing files on other systems.  You need to somehow mount the Windows drive on the Linux system, and then mount it into the container (you cannot force any specific volume mounts in a Dockerfile).  This doesn't really seem like a programming-related question.

Answer (score 0):

Volumes are designed to be attached to running containers and not to the containers used to build the docker image. In case you would like to make your running container accessing a shared file system, you need to attach the volume of the application container during the creation time.  This step depends on what you are using for deploying the containers, but in case you are using docker-compose this can be done as shown below

```
nginxplus:
  image: bhc-nginxplus
  volumes:
  - "${path_on_the_host}:${path_in_the_container}"
```

with docker commands

```
docker run -v ${path_on_the_host}:${path_in_the_container} $image
```